# Caesar Cipher decryption not working for non-alphabetical characters

Tags: java, encryption, modulo

I'm completely new to programming and have been tasked with writing a method in Java to decrypt a message encrypted using a Caesar Cipher (without importing any utilities).

The following code was provided for encrypting a message:

```
    public String encrypt(String plainText, int offset) {
    String cipher = "";
    char[] arr = plainText.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        int numericalVal = (int) arr[i];
        if (Character.isUpperCase(arr[i])) {
            cipher += (char) (((numericalVal + offset - 65) % 26) + 65);
        } else if (numericalVal == 32) { 
            cipher += arr[i];
        }

        else {
            cipher += (char) (((numericalVal + offset - 97) % 26) + 97);
        }
    }
    return cipher;
```

My solution must begin with the line `Public String decrypt(String plainText, int offset)` {

This is how I attempted to solve the problem:

```
    public String decrypt(String plainText, int offset) {
    String decipher = "";
    char[] d_arr = plainText.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < d_arr.length; i++) {
        int numericalVal = (int) d_arr[i];
        if (Character.isUpperCase(d_arr[i])) {
            decipher += (char) ((((numericalVal - offset - 65) % 26 + 26) % 26) + 65); 
            //to get remainder for negative values too
        } else if (numericalVal == 32) { 
            decipher += d_arr[i];
        }

        else {
            decipher += (char) ((((numericalVal - offset - 97) % 26 + 26) % 26) + 97);
        }

    }
    return decipher;
```

This works when decrypting letters of the alphabet, but non-alphabetical letters are not decrypted properly and I am unsure what the issue is.

For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    CaesarCipher C = new CaesarCipher();
    System.out.println(C.encrypt("?", 4)); //returns the ] symbol
    System.out.println(C.decrypt("]", 4)); //returns the letter s
```

We were told that adjusting the code to ignore non-alphabetical characters entirely was possible but would require more work, so I changed the `} else if (numericalVal == 32) {    cipher += arr[i];` code in both the encrypt and decrypt Strings to `} else if (numericalVal < 65 || (numericalVal > 90 && numericalVal < 97) || numericalVal > 122) {   cipher += arr[i];`.

This circumvented the issue but I was told that it's much easier to just decrypt the non-alphabetical characters as well, so I reverted this change, but now I'm at a complete loss as to how to solve this problem. I feel like I'm missing something very simple as I managed to do it "the hard way" but cannot do it the easier way. I can see that when a non-alphabetical value is encrypted, the alphabetical letters are essentially skipped, but the same is not occurring for the decryption process. I presume this is related to the adjustment I made to find the remainder of negative values, but I am unsure.

Comment: afaik Caesar is only expected to work on alpha characters. In fact it would be difficult to do otherwise as character sets vary

Comment: Other hints: if your cipher doesn't contain any state then make the methods `static` so you don't have to instantiate `Cipher`. Otherwise you could think of `Cipher` being constructed using the key, i.e. the shift (or `offset` in your words). Don't use `+ string` in a loop: use a `StringBuilder` instead and initiate it with the right number of characters.

Answer (score 0):

What you generally try and do is to define your own alphabet rather than using the ABC, and put that in a string (or a char array). Then you replace the `- 65` (which is not very great when it comes to encoding, you could have used e.g. just `- 'A'`) by looking up the character in the alphabet.

Then you can perform the modulus operation *on the size of the alphabet*, i.e. `alphabet.length()` for strings or `alphabet.length` for char arrays. Then you perform the modular addition / subtraction, and finally you find the corresponding character in your alphabet again.

Now you have some special code for space and upper / lowercase. That would not work anymore when you'd include special characters. There are two ways around this. The simplest one is to create one big alphabet with uppercase, lowercase and special characters. If you want to keep the case you could also use e.g. 3 separate alphabets.

So you start off with e.g.

```
private static final String ALPHABET = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz,.;";
```

or you could use:

```
private static final String ALPHABET_UPPER = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
private static final String ALPHABET_LOWER = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
private static final String ALPHABET_SIGNS = ",.;";
```

I'd say the single alphabet is a bit more secure as you would directly be able to see the signs in the other. Then again, the Caesar cipher was only somewhat secure when almost nobody was able to read in the first place.

Better split your application into methods, have at least:

- `charToIndex(char c): int`;
- `indexToChar(int i): char`;
- `shiftIndex(int i, int shift): int`.

and while we are at it:

```
public static int mod(int i, int n) {
    return ((i % n) + n) % n;
}
```